# From for loops to matrix computation

Tags: python, vectorization

I've got a piece of code taking an input and checking if the input meets requirements. The input is composed of a `list` of objects called `S`.

```
class S:
    def __init__(self, f, t, tf, timeline):
        self.f = f
        self.t = t
        self.tf = tf
        self.timeline = timeline
```

To know if a combination of objects meets the requirement, I have functions taking a `list` of size `N` of objects and returning `True` or `False`.

```
input1 = [S_1, ..., S_N]

def c1(input1):
    if condition_c1_valid:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now let's consider this example:

```
import itertools

possible_objects = [S(f, t, tf, timeline) for f in [...] for t in [..] ...]
inputs_to_check = list(itertools.combination_with_replacement(possible_objects, 5)

results = list()
for inp in inputs_to_check:
    if c1(inp):
         results.append(inp)
```

Right now, my solution is using a `for` loop on the `N` condition I'm checking every time.
The code keeps the inputs which meets the condition.

**Could this be computed at once in a matrix fashion?** (Vectorized)

I was thinking of something like this: (pseudo code)

```
Data[input, c1, ..., cN]
return where(all(c1, ..., cN) is True)
```

Can anyone tell me if it is achievable, and could point me towards examples? In the end, my list of inputs to check is very large. Thus it would be interesting to send the computation to the GPU. I thought that maybe this could be achieved through Tensorflow...

Thanks for the tips :)

EDIT: The example above is far from the reality. I'm using nested `for` loops on a large `set`, with a complexity of the 6th or 7th degree. The current solution is optimize with generators, but I would like to push this further.

Comment: This could be given a more descriptive title

Comment: @FHTMitchell I'm open to any suggestion, I did not feel very inspirational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most general sense, you won't be able to vectorize this. CPython is notoriously bad at parallel processing due to the GIL and it's primary matrix vectorization library (numpy) is for dealing with primative types (integers, floats, etc.), not python objects such as `S`.

There are a few things that could help:

1. If `f`, `t`, `tf`, `timeline` are numbers (which they look like they
       may be), then you could form four numpy arrays of these values and
       pass those through a vectorized version of `c1` which returns a boolean array. You could then do `np.asarray(input1)[c1_vec(f_vec, t_vec, tf_vec, timeline_vec)]`
2. You said you've used generators instead of lists, but just to be especially sure your example should read as:

   `possible_objects = (S(f, t, tf, timeline) for f in (...) for t in (...) ...)
   inputs_to_check = itertools.combination_with_replacement(possible_objects, 5)
   results = [inp for inp in inputs_to_check if c1(inp)]`

   This saves a lot of time of writing objects to memory that can be avoided.
3. Use PyPy. It uses a JIT compiler to massively speed up python for loops. For very large loops this will get up to near C speed.

---

You mention using a GPU. CPython doesn't even run on more then one CPU core, running this on a GPU would be pointless unless using another implementation.

Comment: Thanks. A lot of information. Going definitely to look into PyPy. timeline is a list of floats, and there are actually other parameters to my objects, so things get tricky, but maybe manageable. I thought so that object could not be passed... Gonna try to passe the attributes instead. For the GPU usage, I thought that matrix computation could be performed faster on it. Example: Matrix multiplication is faster with tensorflow than numpy for large matrix if the GPU is used (large matrix only since the communication is slower with the GPU than the CPU).